# Starting a Sinatra app in a new thread. The thread immediately dies

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra

I have the following Sinatra app defined:

```
require "sinatra/base"

class App < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set port: 5000
  end

  get "/" do
    "Hello!"
  end
end
```

From inside a Rails app, I am trying to start the Sinatra app in the background:

```
Thread.new do
  App.run!
end
```

But it seems that the thread immediately dies. There is nothing keeping it alive.

How can I make it so that the Sinatra app will startup in the new thread and run indefinitely (or for at least the lifetime of the app)?

Comment: App.run! Is a single run right?

Comment: Also why do you want this to run in a new thread?

Comment: @VishnuJ . I found the question and answer useful because in my first try of Sinatra I wanted to do as I usually do: run one line/block after another in pry.  It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thread.new do
    App.run!
end
```

I'm willing to bet that App.run! is raising an exception.  Thread.new with a block has a nasty habit of swallowing exceptions

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6647

Do the following:

```
Thread.new do 
  begin
    App.run!
  rescue StandardError => e
    $stderr << e.message
    $stderr << e.backtrace.join("\n")
  end
end
```

and see whether you see anything logged to stderr.

Comment: Or you could use `Thread::abort_on_exception` to handle this outside the worker thread.